# Function defined as an integral: trapz?

Tags: matlab, integral, pde, fluid-dynamics

I want to calculate a function p of x,y: p(x,y) which is defined by the integral of another function of x and y:

p(x,y) = Integral(indefinite) of v(x,y) dx

Now, if I have a matrix expressing `p` on a uniform grid `x` and `y`, how do I construct the function `p` (which should be a matrix).

Obviously if I integrated using `trapz`, I would obtain a vector:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,10); v=magic(10);
p=trapz(x,v);
size(p)
```

gives `1 10` and not 10 10.

Comment: Your formula `p(x,y) = Integral of v(x,y) dx` doesn't make sense mathematically: how can you integrate over the `x` variable, and the result still depend on `x`? Is your integral indefinite, i.e. the anti-derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

1. the formula for *p* is actually defined like:

*p*(*x*,*y*) = Integral[*x*<sub>0</sub> .. *x*] *v*(*ξ*,*y*) d*ξ*;

2. the integration grid `x` × `y` is uniform, with the norm `dx` × `dy`;
3. the rows of the matrix `v` have `x` constant, first row corresponding the the smallest `x`;

then the integral is:

```
p = cumtrapz(v) * dx;
```